# Do concurrent writes in firebase throw an error?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If you write to the same document in your firebase database at the exact same time (i.e. more than 1 QPS writes per document), does it fail to update the document with an error, or does it fail silently? And, do both writes fail if they happen concurrently or does one complete and the other fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a write fails on the server for any reason, you will receive an error.  There are no silent failures in Firestore.  The level of concurrency doesn't change this behavior.

If you are worried about one write clobbering the data from another write, you should use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to make sure they finish consistently.